# Get a foreign key through a popup

Tags: jquery, yii

I have tried to search before i made a decision to create this new thread.
I would like to make a popup dialog which shows a list of selectable values.
When an item selected, the popup fades out and returns the selected value to the main form.

For example:

Assume I have two tables as follow:
table_a(id, a) and
table_b(id, id_a, B) -> id_a refers to table_a.id

Then, I have a create form for table_b. Of course there would be a field for the 'id_a' attribute.
To ease user input, I want to create a link next to the field which will show a popup window which contains a list of available records to be selected. When user selects one of those records listed, the popup fades out and returns the selected record's id back to the main create form.
Also, if possible, the popup should work like a gridview which able to do such a simple search function.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Do you want to use a popup (new browser window) or a dialog (same page, AJAX request)?

Comment: i would like to make another window, a popup window, could you assist me, how to do that,.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the main form from the popup window with the [window.opener](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp) property. 
Before closing the popup send your value(s) with javascript back to the form.